# ¿Cómo validar la fecha seleccionada de un DateTimePicker en C#?

Tags: c#

Quiero validar un `DateTimePicker` donde si la fecha seleccionada sobrepasa la fecha actual del sistema, no guarde en la base de datos. Si es menor, que permita guardar.

Con el siguiente código me guarda la fecha seleccionada:

```
NpgsqlCommand query = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO miembros (idmiembro,nombre,apellidos,sexo,grupo,fecha_nacimiento,domicilio,status)" + "VALUES ('" + txtId.Text + "','" + txtNombre.Text + "','" + txtApellidos.Text + "','" + txtSexo.Text + "','" + txtGrupo.Text + "' ,'" + txtNacimiento.Text + "' ,'" + txtDomicilio.Text + "' ,'" + txtStatus.Text + "')", cn);
query.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Miembro registrado exitosamente", "◄ AVISO IMPORTANTE ►", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Busque en internet la siguiente sentencia para validarlo pero me marca error:

```
if (txtNacimiento.Text > DateTime.Now.Date)
    MessageBox.Show("fecha mayor a hoY");
{
    MessageBox.Show("fecha menor a hoY");
}
```

Comment: Hola Karol, ¿tienes algún ejemplo del código que has intentado? Con esto sería más fácil poder ayudarte en cuanto al problema que presentas :)

Comment: si ahorita lo agrego

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te pone con el ejemplo de código que pones?

Comment: en la condidion del if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El código que encontraste en Internet tiene cosas por mejorar, por ejemplo, está mal estructurado el `if`, además de que supongo que estás intentando validar un `TextBox` con `txtNacimiento.Text`. La correción quedaría de la siguiente forma suponiendo que tus `DateTimePicker`s se llaman `dateTimePicker1`, `dateTimePicker2`, `dateTimePicker3`:

```
if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date
    && dateTimePicker2.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date
    && dateTimePicker3.Value.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date)
{
    //Lógica de guardado en base de datos
}
else
    //Mensaje de que no es posible guardar la info por la fecha
```

Comment: gracias me sirvio tu ayuda pero en caso de que tenga 3 DateTimePicker como podria ser?

Comment: @karol ¿requieres validar tres `DateDimePicker` contra la fecha actual?

Comment: si es que tengo 3 opciones donde el usuario debe poner una fecha entonces por eso utilizo los 3 DataTimePicker

Comment: @karol en este caso tendrías que hacer la comparación uno a uno, edité mi respuesta para que te bases en eso :)

Comment: ahhhh ok gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

> Usando DATETIME.COMPARE

```
   DateTime fecha_nac= DateTime.TryParse(txtNacimiento.Text);
   int result = DateTime.Compare(fecha_nac, DateTime.Today);

   string compara;
        if (result < 0)
            compara= "la fecha de nacimiento es menor que la actual";

        else if (result == 0)
            compara= "las fechas coniciden";

        else
            compara= "la fecha de nacimiento es superiorr a la actual";
```

> Usando TimeSpan

Te permite obtener la diferencias en horas,dias etc.. Ejemplo:

```
DateTime horacorta = DateTime.TryParse(txtNacimiento.Text);
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Today - horacorta;
int diferencia = ts.Days;

 //Tu logica

   if(diferencia==0)
     {
       //Logica
     }
```

Comment: @Rastaloverly solo era necesario `DateTime.Today` a que hagas `DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())`. Además, para obtener la fecha de un texto se debería usar `DateTime.TryParse`, donde podrías obtener si fué convertido correctamente como el valor en tipo fecha.

Comment: haaa ok  muchas gracias por tus comentarios, edito mi respuesta. Saludos

Comment: gracias por responder :)

Answer (score 0):

Si la fecha la tienes en un `TextBox` (es lo que parece ya que tratas de comparar `txtNacimiento`) lo que debes haces es convertirlo a `DateTime` y después comparar:

```
DateTime dtNacimiento = DateTime.Parse(txtNacimiento.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
if (dtNacimiento.Date>DateTime.Now.Date)
{
        //....
}
```

Como he comentado en otra respuesta hoy mismo, para trabajar con fechas **siempre** es preferible utilizar `DateTime` ,por ejemplo como este caso para comparaciones.

Comment: Gracias por responder mi pregunta :)